# Spring Boot GraphQL MultiPart File Upload Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, graphql, integration-testing

How to test file upload with Spring Boot GraphQLTester. When I am using curl the request looks

```
curl localhost:8080/graphql \
  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { singleUpload(file: $file) }", "variables": { "file": null } }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"] }' \
  -F 0=@test.txt
```

The problem is I can't set form data from my Client

```
@GraphQlTest(FileController.class)
@Import({GraphQLTestConfiguration.class})
class FileGraphQLControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private GraphQlTester graphQlTester;
```

In the **graphQlTester** client, I don't have methods to set the file as data-form

```
   String mutation = """
                mutation ($file: Upload!) {
                    singleUpload(file: $file)
                }
                """;


 graphQlTester.document(mutation) // how to set file here
            .execute()
            .path("/singleUpload")
            .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring GraphQL does not support file upload yet, check discussion here, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/pull/430, so currently Spring GraphQL test tools is not ready for the file upload.

If you have already implemented GraphQL multiple file upload feature(eg. via https://github.com/nkonev/multipart-spring-graphql or used other GraphQL frameworks for backend), in the tests, you can use the raw Spring `RestTemplate` or `WebClient`(for webflux stack) to send files to backend server.

An example that using TestRestTemplate is here: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/blob/master/graphql-java-kickstart/src/test/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplicationTests.java#L77, read the [GraphQL file upload best practice](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/file-upload-best-practices) to know well about related schema definition.